# Listing all system exit status codes with descriptions

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, exit

I know `$?` from shell holds the last executed programs `exit status`.

For example, when I run below commands, I saw different status for different situation.

```
test$ hello
-bash: hello: command not found
test$ echo $?
127
test$ expr 1 / 0
expr: division by zero
test$ echo $?
2
```

I was wondering if there is any common exit status list in system or internet where i can get all the exit status with their descriptions. I found a list [here](http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html), but some codes are missing, for example `status code 127`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be no comprehensive list, because the meaning of command exit statuses is inherently command-specific. For a given command, you can usually get information about this on the respective command's manual page and Info documents.

In the case of

```
test$ hello
-bash: hello: command not found
test$ echo $?
127
```

the exit code `127` comes from `bash`, because the requested command itself couldn't be found.

In the case of

```
test$ expr 1 / 0
expr: division by zero
test$ echo $?
2
```

the exit code `2` comes from `expr`.

Some of these commands might be standardized or at least coordinated for several commands or a group of commands (e.g. "`sh`-compatible shells", I could imagine), but unless a command wants to conform to one of these conventions (and there are probably multiple conflicting conventions around), the command's authors are completely free to decide what they want their exit status codes to mean.

There's one important exception: **All UNIX commands should adhere to this loose rule** to be good citizens and provide meaningful composability (e.g. with pipes) on the command line:

- `0` means 'success' or "true"/"truthy"
- non-`0` means (in a very broad sense) 'failure' or 'non-success' or "false"/"falsy"

As you can see, this still leaves a lot of room for interpretation, which is perfectly intended, because these meanings must be specific to the context of the individual commands. (Consider e.g. the `false` command, that has the very purpose to "fail", thus always returns a non-`0` exit code.)

The [list](http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html) you found describes return codes for system calls. System calls are when a program makes a request (in)to the kernel and are not the same as command invocation, thus these return codes are not (necessarily) the same as command exit codes.

Comment: Worth noting that an exit status of 1 almost *always* means "general error", rather than indicating any specific kind of error.

Comment: @chepner ...Any clue why, usually, 0 means success? I've been into computing professionally since 1978, I think (if not it was '79) and we didn't have that convention but the opposite; 1, true, was the "it's all OK", and 0, false, was "oops!" Then I joined DEC in '83 and ... nevermind. But, importantly, along all the years I've known about this "0 means success" idiom, I've asked people if they have any clue where it came from and the best answer was PURE speculation - admittedly - from the respondent: it means "nothing to report."

Comment: Also just speculation, but apart from the rather philosophical 0 ≃ "nothing to report" = "everything OK", there might be a mostly practical side to it: There's usually only "one" way a command can succeed, but often multiple how it can fail, so you'd need a special value for success and all other values for distinguishing various failure modes. 0 kinda is a special number, so it might make sense to use it as that special value.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status provides a broader example of how exit statuses have been used in other operating system. OpenVMS is interesting: odd means success, even means failure.

Comment: @RichardT "zero" for "success" is mostly for testing in a shell script, because the "test" (or "[") shell command returns "false" if its argument is non-zero. So simple shell testing for correct completion of a command would typically have "if test command; then echo 'ERROR!'; fi" Arcane, I know.

Answer (score 3):

The exit status is a numeric value that is returned by a program to the calling program or shell. In C programs, this is represented by the return value of the `main()` function or the value you give to `exit(3)`. The only part of the number that matters are the least significant 8 bits, which means there are only values from `0` to `255`.

```
Code    Description
0       success
1-255   failure (in general)
126     the requested command (file) can't be executed (but was found)
127     command (file) not found
128     according to ABS it's used to report an invalid argument to the exit 
        builtin, but I wasn't able to verify that in the source code of Bash 
        (see code 255)
128 + N the shell was terminated by the signal N (also used like this by 
        various other programs)
255     wrong argument to the exit builtin (see code 128)
```

The lower codes `0` to `125` are not reserved and may be used for whatever the program likes to report. A value of 0 means successful termination, a value not 0 means unsuccessful termination. This behaviour `(== 0, != 0)` is also what Bash reacts on in some code flow control statements like `if` or `while`.

The above excerpt taken from [Exit Status](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/dict/terms/exit_status) section from [Bash Hackers Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/start).

Answer (score 1):

The list you showed is really the closest possible thing to a "standardization", but frankly it looks more legit than it actually is. As far as I am aware of, almost no one pays much attention to these guys, but instead everyone names their own exit statuses:

Execute test1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
a=10 ; [ "$a" -eq 9 ] && echo "Cool!" || exit 200
```

Output:

```
:~$ test1.sh
:~$ echo $?
200
```

Comment: People pay plenty of attention to that list; it just isn't a list of process exit statuses, but a list of system call return values.